# Form handling PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I am new in PHP and javascript programming. I have a link which is being echoed using PHP.

```
<?php .....echo "<td><font class='calendar'><a onclick='showevent($currentday)' href='#'>". $currentday. "</a></font></td>"; ....?>
```

I will need to call a function showevent() from the link above.

```
<script>

function showevent($day){
     $thisday = $day;
     document.showevent.submit();
}

</script>
```

The function will submit a form as below:

```
<form action="./event.php" name="showevent" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="showevent" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="month" value="<?php echo $cMonth;?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="<?php echo $cYear; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="day" value="<?php echo $thisday; ?>" />
</form>
```

The javascript function does not work. Any one can help to advice and guide me?

Full html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/mystyle.css">
<script>
function showevent($day){
    $thisday = $day;
    document.showevent.submit();
}</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="menutitle">Event Calendar</p>
    <?php



    $monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
            "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])){
        $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
    }
    if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) {
        $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
    }

    $cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
    $cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];

    $prev_year = $cYear;
    $next_year = $cYear;
    $prev_month = $cMonth-1;
    $next_month = $cMonth+1;

    if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
        $prev_month = 12;
        $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
    }
    if ($next_month == 13 ) {
        $next_month = 1;
        $next_year = $cYear + 1;
    }
    ?>

    <table class="calendar">
        <tr align="center">
            <td class="calendarTop">
                <table class="calendarNav">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="calendarOption" onmouseover="this.className='calendarOptionHover'" onmouseout="this.className='calendarOption'" align="center"><a href="#" onclick="document.forms.prev.submit()">Previous</a>
                        </td>
                        <td width="60%"><p class="subtitle"><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></p></td>
                        <td class="calendarOption" onmouseover="this.className='calendarOptionHover'" onmouseout="this.className='calendarOption'" align="center"><a href="#" onclick="document.forms.next.submit()">Next</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
                <table class="calendarTop">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="calendarTitle" ><font>S</font>
                        </td>
                        <td class="calendarTitle" ><font>M</font>
                        </td>
                        <td class="calendarTitle" ><font>T</font>
                        </td>
                        <td class="calendarTitle" ><font>W</font>
                        </td>
                        <td class="calendarTitle" ><font>T</font>
                        </td>
                        <td class="calendarTitle" ><font>F</font>
                        </td>
                        <td class="calendarTitle" ><font>S</font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php 

                    require "./dbconnect.php";

                    $result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM event WHERE month = $cMonth AND year=$cYear ORDER BY date"); //---->resource

                    $before =0;
                    $after =99;
                    $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
                    $maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
                    // $cMonth;  ---> month name
                    $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
                    $startday = $thismonth['wday'];
                    $eventday = Array(31);
                    for ($k =0; $k<32; $k++){
                        $eventday[$k]=false;
                    }
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $eventday[$row['date']]=true;
                    }

                    for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
                    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                    }
                    if($i < $startday) {
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }else{
                        $currentday = ($i - $startday + 1);
                        if($eventday[$currentday] == true){

                            echo "<td class='eventtrue'><font class='calendar'><a onclick='javascript: showevent($currentday);' href='#'>". $currentday. "</a></font></td>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<td class='eventfalse'><font class='calendar'>". ($i - $startday + 1). "</font></td>";
}
                    }//--2 brackets

                    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) {
                        echo "</tr>";

                }
}

?>

                </table>
        <tr>
            <td><form action="./event.php" name="prev" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="calendar" /> <input
                        type="hidden" name="month" value="<?php echo $prev_month;?>" /> <input
                        type="hidden" name="year" value="<?php echo $prev_year; ?>" />
                </form>
                <form action="./event.php" name="next" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="calendar" /> <input
                        type="hidden" name="month" value="<?php echo $next_month;?>" /> <input
                        type="hidden" name="year" value="<?php echo $next_year; ?>" />
                </form>
                <form action="./event.php" name="showevent" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="showevent" /> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="month" value="<?php echo $cMonth;?>" /> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="<?php echo $cYear; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="day" value="<?php echo $thisday; ?>" />
                </form></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the final html code which you are creating with php?

Comment: You can't mix PHP and Javascript.

Comment: @cryptic that was me being tired. Yes the variable is being sent "correctly" to the javascript function.

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome and watch the syntax errors appear.

Comment: @Alex, the string is inside double quotes so it will be parsed where variables will be interpreted.

Comment: thanks all for response. I have posted the full html code. Still need some advice on which parts is going wrong.

Comment: @ChangJitKang `<script>
function showevent($day){
    $thisday = $day;
    document.showevent.submit();
}</script>` is all wrong. You **can't** mix PHP with Javascript.

Comment: @cryptic, how am I suppose to correct it?

Comment: @cryptic if I'm not mistaken he could just use <script> function showevent(day){ var thisday = day; document.showevent.submit(); }</script>

Comment: @Alex, more correct, but what does assigning a value to a variable that doesn't get used accomplish? OP is wanting the value to do something. I assume OP wants it inserted into the form field, but not sure.

Comment: @alex, I tried to use your code, but it still not working, is there anything wrong on the link that is calling the function?

Comment: @cryptic, I am trying to pass the var this day to the form so that next page can use POST method to get the require value.

Comment: @ChangJitKang No when calling the function there should be no problem.  What do you use the $day = $thisday; for?

Comment: @ChangJitKang, try below.

Comment: @ChangJitKang btw you have 3 forms, I assume you wanted the value inserted into showevent form's day field.

Comment: @Alex, hard to explain the usage by way, just like cryptic said, passing the value to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function showevent(day)
{
    alert(day); // test if it triggers
    document.showevent.day.value = day;
    document.showevent.submit();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Also:

`<a onclick='javascript: showevent($currentday);'`

should be:

`<a onclick='return showevent($currentday);'`

Comment: I tried your method, but the script doesn't seems to be called. Is there any way i could test whether the script is being called?

Comment: @ChangJitKang, try above, should have an alert box show up with the day.

Comment: The alert box does not show up. The other javescript on the page work perfectly, except the link that calling up the javascript won't work.

Comment: @ChangJitKang, what does the browser's error console say?

Comment: viewed the error console and it is empty.

Comment: @ChangJitKang, please follow my latest edit. You had the onclick wrong. You were specifying a javascript: uri which you were not suppose to.

Comment: edited to your latest code. Error found in console: onclick not object

Comment: check your HTML source in browser and post the HTML link it is outputting.

Comment: content too long, it is pointing to this: <font class='calendar'><a onclick='return showevent(12);' href='#'>12</a></font>

Comment: @ChangJitKang, verify that the javascript inside the `<script>` tags is exactly as mine above. The only way you will get the object error I can think of is that it is trying to reference a var with a $ in it as you had in previous code, which would not work, as you were not creating an object.

Comment: I following exactly the same as your code and the script tag contain no $ type var. Is the onclick='return showevent($currentday)' causing issue as it do contain $ type var? Is that possible if I move the function from script tag into the php tag?

Comment: it is being properly output into the HTML so it is not causing a problem as far as I can see. Is there any way you can link me to the page in question? You can delete the link afterwards.

Comment: @ChangJitKang, put the javascript above inside `myscript.js` my browser says the function is not existing.

Comment: i tried put into it, but error console still giving same error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: Also your HTML is extremely malformed, so it will cause you tons of problems down the road with layout and javascript. Please fix these errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F110.159.155.169%2Fbeta%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 run each page through that validator.

Comment: @ChangJitKang, you have `<script src="./script/myscript.js"></script>` twice in your code. Remove one, as you can't declare functions twice. You will likely fix all this when you fix the errors in above link.

Comment: thanks a lot and will post an update here after I perform the fix.

Comment: I fixed all the error shown in the validator. The script still won't working and giving me error

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!! The source of problem is the name conflict as I used same name for javascript function and form. Changed one of the name, and it works.

Comment: Yay! Btw don't use forms like you are doing instead use URLs like example.php?day=12&month=3&year=2012 then access those values in example.php with $_GET['day'], $_GET['month'] etc...

Answer (score -2):

Please add type to the script tag and try

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showevent($day){
     $thisday = $day;
     document.showevent.submit();
}

</script>
```

Hope this might help you in your problem....

Comment: In HTML5 the type may be omitted, JS will be assumed.